# Linear Algebra: parametric line in 3d

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook gives me a parametric line, L, as follows:

\begin{array}{11} 
x = 1 - t \\
y = 2  + 0t\\
z = -1 +4t
\end{array}

The book continues on to say that this line is parallel to the xz-plane since y = 2. However, plotting the line causes me some confusion:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omj2w.png

The image tells me that the line is not parallel to the red-green plane and that y = 2 simply implies that for every increment of t, y is increased by 2.

What am I missing?

Comment: Green is the y-axis.

Comment: this is right since $y=2$ is constant

Answer (score 0):

"For every increment of $t$, $y$ is increased by 2."

No, $y=2$ and never varies with $t$. All points on the parametric line $(1-t,2,-1+4t)$ have a $y$ coordinate equal to $2$. Thus the line is parallel to the $xz$ plane.